# Kafka stream to spark does not reduce counts

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

I am trying a basic example of streaming from **kafka** to **spark**. I am very new to **spark** and have little experience.

My program is as follows (copied from the examples in apache-spark):

```
if (args.length < 4) {
        System.err.println("Usage: JavaKafkaWordCount <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String zkQuorum = args[0];
    String groupId = args[1];
    String topicsToListen = args[2];
    String numOfThread = args[3];

    StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels();
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount");
    // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));

    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(numOfThread);
    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] topics = topicsToListen.split(",");
    for (String topic : topics) {
        topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
    }

    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zkQuorum, groupId, topicMap);

    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);

    JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
            .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

    wordCounts.print();
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
```

And then I start my **kafka-broker** and run the built jar by producing the following command:

> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class "JavaKafkaWordCount" --master local[2] PATH_TO_JAR/kafka-spark-streaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar localhost:2181 test-consumer-group test 1

And when I produce some words from the **kafka-producer** I am expecting the count of a word published multiple times to increase, but all I see is the word and the **count** as 1 printed for every new publish:

> (hello, 1)

I was expecting the count to increase when I publish the same word more than once,

> (hello, 2)

but that's not happening. What exactly have I understood wrong here and is it something to do with the arguments I pass tot he job or is it what the job is meant to do?

Can someone give some insight?

Thanks
SHabir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the code a couple of times I managed to identify why I always get the **count** per word as just 1 and not an **aggregated total**.

In the following line:

```
// Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
```

I set the **interval** between successive reads from the stream as **2 seconds**. I realized that I am not producing enough content of the same string within this interval *(2 seconds)* at the producer end to get an aggregated result.

However, when I increase this interval to like **10000 millis** *(10 sec)*, then I could produce multiple lines of data from the **kafka-producer**. These lines are duly processed by the job and similar string counts are nicely aggregated for that specific interval.

> (hello, 4)
>
> (world, 6)

Thanks Very Much
Shabir